# Filter pandas crosstabe based on column sums

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python3 and pandas for a dataset which is shown as follows (toy dataset)-

```
data
      location importance    agent  count
0       London        Low  chatbot      2
1          NYC     Medium  chatbot      1
2       London       High    human      3
3       London        Low    human      4
4          NYC       High    human      1
5          NYC     Medium  chatbot      2
6    Melbourne        Low  chatbot      3
7    Melbourne        Low    human      4
8    Melbourne       High    human      5
9          NYC       High  chatbot      5
10   Melbourne        Low    human      3
11   Melbourne        Low    human      1
12   Melbourne       High  chatbot      5
13  Washington     Medium  chatbot      7
14  Washington     Medium    human      8
15  Washington       High  chatbot      5
16   Melbourne     Medium  chatbot      4
17  Washington     Medium  chatbot      5
18   Melbourne       High    human      3
19  Washington        Low  chatbot      2
```

pandas crosstab is applied as follows-

```
pd.crosstab(data['location'], data['importance'])

importance  High  Low  Medium
location                     
London         1    2       0
Melbourne      3    4       1
NYC            2    0       2
Washington     1    1       3
```

The problem is to sum the 3 columns 'High', 'Low', 'Medium' such that you only include rows of crosstab for which sum >= 4. Hence, for this example, it should exclude London since it's column sum < 4.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum rows values and compare by `4` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(data['location'], data['importance'])


df = df1[df1.sum(axis=1).ge(4)]
```

working like:

```
df = df1[df1.sum(axis=1)>= 4)]
```